# Create a pipe-able function that can reduce results

Tags: powershell

In my script I'm joining-by-comma a lot and would like to create a helper function that I can pipe so I could do

```
$fileNames | %{ "../$_.js" } | Join-ByComma
```

rather than having to do

```
($fileNames | %{ "../$_.js" }) -join ', '
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in a way that works with pipeline input. I've tried something like this

```
function Join-ByComma($arr) { 
    $arr -join ', '
}
```

and

```
function Join-ByComma($arr) { 
    Process { $_ }
    End { $arr -join ', ' }
}
```

and neither works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$Input` auto-variable, that represent pipeline input:

```powershell
function Join-ByComma {
    @($Input) -join ', '
}
```